# Library PullToRefresh's method setRefreshing() doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, pull-to-refresh

I'm using this library: [PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) of Chris Banes

I'm trying to synchronize the method setRefreshing() (or setRefreshing(boolean)) to make the view on ListView appear as "Loading" but it doesn't work.

I tried to do as setMode(Mode.MANUAL_REFRESHING) as well but didn't work.
When I refresh pulling it works, yes.

I set it on onCreateView(), and onPreExecute of my AsyncTask and neither it worked.

Thanks in advance.

---

This is how I declare the PullToRefreshListView

```
    lv = (PullToRefreshListView) layout.findViewById(R.id.messaggiListView);
    lv.setPullToRefreshOverScrollEnabled(false);
    lv.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener<ListView>(){

        @Override
        public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
            ChiamataGETMessaggi chiamata = new ChiamataGETMessaggi();
            chiamata.execute(WS.anteprime(HomeActivity.auth));              
        }

    });
```

this is how I set the refresh method on my AsyncTask:

```
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            lv.setRefreshing();
        }
```

This is how I declare it on my XML.

```
    <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
    android:id="@+id/messaggiListView" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_above="@+id/ultimoAccessoContainer" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/rlScrivi" 
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
```

---

**SOLUTION**

I don't know why, I was calling even after the view was initialized but didn't work...  (I mean, onCreateView). Dave Morrissey gave me the solution to work, on UI thread, but I didn't know why it didn't work... just I implemented this on my onPreExecute() of my AsyncTask:

```
    new Thread() {
        public void run() {
                try {
                    main.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            lv.setRefreshing(true); 
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }.start();
```

and now it works. Thanks.

Comment: Post your fragment code and xml position of your listview please

Comment: I'm not sure, but I wonder whether calling these methods from the `AsyncTask` fails because you aren't on the UI thread. Could you try calling these methods from your `Activity` at the point you start the `AsyncTask`, so the call happens on the UI thread?

Comment: Hi @DaveMorrissey, I was trying to do it also onCreateView.... isn't that also the UI thread ?? because I have implemented a runOnUiThread() and now it works... you gave me the final touch I'd say... could you post it as answer and I mark it as correct?

Comment: Yes, `onCreateView` is in the UI thread but I guess the view isn't initialised at that stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `setRefreshing()` methods are called from an AsyncTask, you aren't on the UI thread so the UI update fails. Possible alternatives are to call this method immediately before starting the AsyncTask, or to make sure the call is posted to the UI thread while the task is running.

Comment: AsyncTask.onPreExecute() runs on the UI thread. He is calling setRefreshing() from this method.

Answer (score 1):

This bug maybe caused by the `mHeaderLayout` not yet fully initialized when you call `setRefreshing(true)` at the beginning of a application.

Go to method `onRefreshing(final boolean doScroll)` in class `PullToRefreshBase`

Find the line: `smoothScrollTo(-getHeaderSize(), listener);`

And replace `getHeaderSize()` with `-146`:

**`smoothScrollTo(-146, listener);`**

`146` is loged from the result of `getHeaderSize()` when it works normally.

If you have a customized `mHeaderLayout`, you may have a different result of `getHeaderSize()`, then use your number instead.